# Count how much specific words are in a database row

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I have two lists of words and a database with more than thousand news articles.

I want to count how many of the words from the lists **$badwords** and **$goodwords** are in each article in my database. Next, I would like to save the two outcomes (of $badwords and $goodwords) per row in the columns **badwords** and **goodwords**. I will run this script with a **cronjob**.

**My current table structure** *The last two rows are empty*

```
TABLE news
-----------------
|ID|newstitle|newscontent|badwords|goodwords|
|1| Rain in London | It is horrible depressive weather in this nice city. | EMPTY | EMPTY |
|2| France wins the WorldCup | The player made a great goal. | EMPTY | EMPTY |
```

**My desired table structure**
*The number of $badwords and $goodwords in the last two columns*

```
TABLE news
-----------------
|ID|newstitle|newscontent|badwords|goodwords|
|1| Rain in London | It is horrible depressive weather in this nice city. | 2 | 1 |
|2| France wins the WorldCup | The player made a great goal. | 0 | 1 |
```

**My current PHP code**

```
<?php
//the wordlists
$badwords = "depressive horrible";
$goodwords = "great";

//connection to the database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// here is my sql query

$sql = " UPDATE news
set badwords = (SELECT count (*) from news
where newscontent LIKE '.%$badwords%.')";    

//close the connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Leon, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: I'm sorry Leon, but it remains obscure: i.e., you want perform the count in mysql or in php? what does it mean “based on a string with words”? Please add more details and **provide concrete example(s):** table structure, field content example, string example, desired result example, ect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to check if a certain wordlist exists in your database. In that case you're looking for a query like so (also use escaping in your queries depending on the db-class you use, e.g. [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)()):

```
SELECT    COUNT(*) AS `count`
         ,`newscontent` 
FROM      `news`
WHERE     `newscontent` = '" . $wordlist . "'
```

If you want to display how many times each wordlist exists in your database this is what you need:

```
SELECT    COUNT(*) AS `count`
         ,`newscontent` 
FROM      `news`
GROUP BY  `newscontent`
```

If you want to display how many strings you have for a given number of words this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php
  $sql = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
  $query = $sql->query('select * from `news`');
  $summary = [];

  while($record = $query->fetch_object()) { 
    $summary[count(explode(' ', $record->newscontent))]++;
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($summary);
  echo '</pre>';
```

If none of the above are what you're looking for than, after 4 times of reading your question, I literally have no clue what you're after.

**Updated answer**
Since you've updated your question I understand what you want. See the updated answer below.

```
<?php
  // your db connection ...

  // array with good and bad words
  $good = [
    'awesome',
    'neat',
    'fantastic',
    'great',
    // and so on
  ];

  $bad = [
    'horrible',
    'worst',
    'bad',
    'terrific',
    // and so on
  ];

  // if you keep using your string approach you can set $good and $bad with $good = explode(' ', $goodwords); and $bad = explode(' ', $badwords);

  // fetch the record you need
  $query = $sql->query('select * from `news` where `ID` = 1'); // insert parameter for your ID here instead of just 1
  $newsitem = $query->fetch_object();

  // set up good and bad word counters
  $totalGood = 0;
  $totalBad = 0;

  // check how many times each word is mentioned in newscontent
  foreach($good as $word) { 
    // add spaces arround the word to make sure the full word is matched, not a part
    $totalGood += substr_count($newsitem->newscontent, ' ' . $word . ' ');
  }

  // check how many times each word is mentioned in newscontent
  foreach($bad as $word) { 
    // add spaces arround the word to make sure the full word is matched, not a part
    $totalBad += substr_count($newsitem->newscontent, ' ' . $word . ' ');
  }  

  // update the record
  $sql->query("
    update `news` 
    set `badwords` = " . $totalBad . ",
        `goodword` = " . $totalGood . "
    where `ID` = " . $newsitem->ID);
```

An interesting thing on text interpretation remains sarcasm. How would you deal with something like "Well, the weather in England is great again - as usual!" ;) Good luck though!

Comment: Thank you very much @Ben! I rephrased my question and indeed, I was looking for a bit different solution. A combination of your approaches should do the trick.. However,  I did not manage a solution so far.